# Gradle Project Sync failed and tried clean and rebuild but didnt work

Tags: android, android-studio

Please check the following errors and help me solve this, I have tried some steps like clean and rebuild and downloaded the latest gradle and replaced it in the gradle path but none of them worked.

**Screenshot of error message in android studio**
[image]

Comment: post your build.gradle files..

Comment: i am a newbie, i really don't know where to find those files

Comment: go to left under android pane...go below to see the buld.gradle files..open andcopy past the code and post it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/avFyf


please check this link for snip of the code

Comment: change `26.1.0` to `26.0.2`

Comment: and add `buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"` under your `compileSdkVersion`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ab8WD

still the same

Comment: `buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"` add this not `26.0.1` and do one more thing... go to *Tools - > Android - > Sync Project With Gradle Files* at the top

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/dMouZ

No result

Comment: now go to *File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Gradle -> Uncheck offline work* do you have internet connection?

Comment: it is already in uncheck mode, and yes i have internet connection

Comment: Issue resolved...it was the antivirus..firewall and internet protection that was blocking the maven  download...

but seriously thank you for helping me out.